# Create 3 input AND from 2 input NANDs

Tags: digital-logic

Is this the correct result?

a and b and c = not((a nand b) or not c)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS5EKQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is there any better decomposition?

Comment: Have you written out the truth table for your circuit? does it match what you expect?

Comment: "Is there any better decomposition?" yeah one that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overthinking this. You probably know that \$\mathsf{and}(x,y) = \mathsf{not}(\mathsf{nand}(x,y))\$, and negation can be implemented using \$\mathsf{not}(x) = \mathsf{nand}(x,x)\$ or \$\mathsf{not}(x) = \mathsf{nand}(x, \mathbf{1})\$.

Here,
$$ r = \mathsf{and}_3(x,y,z) = \mathsf{and}(\mathsf{and}(x,y), z),$$
and you can do no better than using 4 nand-gates:

$$ w = \mathsf{and}(x, y) = \mathsf{not}(\mathsf{nand}(x,y)) \\
r = \mathsf{and}(w, z) = \mathsf{not}(\mathsf{nand}(z,w))
$$